# authorization error using linqtotwitter for streaming api

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, linq-to-twitter

i'm trying to get a stream of tweets using LinqToTwitter library and the below c# code, but i get this error:

> Error 401 Unauthorized

```
public static SingleUserAuthorizer auth;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task = new Task(getStreamOfTweets);
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async void getStreamOfTweets()
    {
        auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = CUSTOMER_KEY,
                ConsumerSecret = CUSTOMER_SECRET,
                AccessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN,
                AccessTokenSecret = ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
            }
        };
        var context = new TwitterContext(auth);
        int count = 0;
        await (from strm in context.Streaming
               where strm.Type == StreamingType.Filter
               && strm.Track == "federer"
               select strm)
            .StartAsync(async strm =>
            {
                string message =
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(strm.Content) ?
                        "Keep-Alive" : strm.Content;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    (count + 1).ToString() +
                    ". " + DateTime.Now +
                    ": " + message + "\n");

                if (count++ == 5)
                    strm.CloseStream();
            });
    }
```

**notes:**

- the permission in twitter app is "Read, Write and Access direct messages"
- i can get tweet by REST API correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was because the **timing** in PC was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [LINQ to Twitter FAQ](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/LINQ-to-Twitter-FAQ), which has an extensive section on resolving 401 errors. That said, if it's working for the REST API, but not Streaming, that might narrow the options to try. Here are a couple things to try first:

1. Double check the keys to make sure you didn't accidentally add a space or lose a character on the ends.
2. Give a little time before trying again because sometimes too many accesses or failed attempts might cause them to deny your connection for a certain period of time.
3. Re: #2, try another stream, like Sample.
4. There are a lot of moving parts in play for using OAuth, so work through that list in case you might have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

this issue happens because the time of windows was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied & pasted from the Linq"Twitter sample code, make sure you have set properly all the keys:

```
  ConsumerKey 
  ConsumerSecret 
  AccessToken 
  AccessTokenSecret
```

Then dont use "Application only" auth, use "user auth" instead for streaming which uses all of the above keys.